from google.protobuf import runtime_version as runtime_version ImportError: cannot import name 'runtime_version' from 'google.protobuf'
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x {IMAGE_PATH + '/train'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/train.record'}

!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x{IMAGE_PATH + '/test'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/test.record'}

when i tried to run that code, i have some errors.
error message :
from google.protobuf import runtime_version as runtime_version
 ImportError: cannot import name 'runtime_version' from 'google.protobuf' (C:\Users\VERRA HALIZZAH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\__init__.py)

how to solve this?
im using tensorflow 2.10.1 and protobuff 3.19.6

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
